# Python __metaclass__

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

Есть следующий код:

```
def upper_attr(class_name, class_parents, class_attrs):
    attr = dict((key.upper(), value) for key, value in class_attrs.items() if not key.startswith('__'))
    return type(class_name, class_parents, attr)
class My(object):
    __metaclass__ = upper_attr
    var = 'hello world'
obj = My()
print(hasattr(obj, 'var'))
```

Ожидаю получить `False`, так как `__metaclass__` переводит названия всех атрибутов в верхний регистр, но получаю `True`, где я ошибся?

Но если сделать так:

```
class My(metaclass=upper_attr):
    ...
```

То все работает, почему же не работает с `__metaclass__` не имею понятия.

Comment: Я посмотрел код False True это показывает есть атрибут в классе или нет

Comment: hasattr(object, name) - Имеет ли объект атрибут с именем 'name'.

Comment: @Александр я это знаю, оно возвращает `True` а должно `False`,  вы знакомы с метаклассами?

Comment: Извините ) я не подумав ляпнул, я метаклассы  изучаю . Вы не могли бы построчно пояснить что вы сделали ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код для python3:

```
class MetaClass(type):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = type.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        for key, value in list(obj.__dict__.items()):
            if (key[0] == '_') and (key[-1] == '_'):
                continue
            else:
                obj.__dict__[key.upper()] = value
                del obj.__dict__[key]
        return obj


class My(object, metaclass=MetaClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 'hello world'


obj = My()
print(obj.__dict__)
print(hasattr(obj, 'var'))
```

Comment: А если мне нужно изменить все классы в моем модуле? Меня интересует конкретно пример с `__metaclass__`, если я пишу `metaclass = upper_attr` у меня также все работает

Comment: Не очень понимаю о чем вы. 1.Для каждого нового класса нужно указывать метакласс. 2. Если с upper_attr то же все работает  то ок, юзайте это

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, вы используете Python 3, а не Python 2. В Python 3 поменялся синтаксис и теперь вместо `__metaclass__` следует писать так:

```
class My(metaclass=upper_attr):
    var = 'hello world'
```

Comment: А как мне к примеру сделать это общим для всех классов в модуле?

Comment: Используя в точности метаклассы - только руками прописав метаклассы всем классам модуля. Вообще говоря, это звучит как [ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy). Например, после переименования статических полей нужно, чтобы _весь_ код (даже тот, что был внутри класса) обращался к ним по новому имени. Если вы не можете менять модули - непонятно, как этого достичь.

Answer (score 0):

`__metaclass__` был доступен в 2 питоне как механизм перехода на "new-style classes", и позволял устанавливать метакласс на уровне модуля.

В 3 питоне такой возможности нет, но есть небольшой хак с использованием `__build_class__`:

```py
import builtins


class Meta(type):

    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Meta, cls).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls.extra = "hello world"


__metaclass__ = Meta
__build_class__ = builtins.__build_class__


def build_class_hook(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs["metaclass"] = __metaclass__
    return __build_class__(*args, **kwargs)


builtins.__build_class__ = build_class_hook


class F:
    pass


print(F.extra)  # hello world
```

Я называю это хаком не просто так, `__build_class__` это деталь имплементации конкретной версии питона, поэтому расчитывать на него нельзя.

Более того, `__build_class__` не описан документацией, так что никаких гарантий что он будет работать в будущих версиях питона - нет.

Answer (score -1):

**Вот нашёл идентичный вашему код сдесь всё правильно надеюсь он поможет вам найти ошибку**

```
def upper_attr(future_class_name, future_class_parents, future_class_attr):
    # берем любой атрибут, не начинающийся с '__'
    attrs = ((name, value) for name, value in future_class_attr.items() if not name.startswith('__'))
    # переводим их в верхний регистр
    uppercase_attr = dict((name.upper(), value) for name, value in attrs)

    # создаем класс с помощью 'type'
    return type(future_class_name, future_class_parents, uppercase_attr)

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = upper_attr
    bar = 'bip'

print (hasattr(Foo, 'bar'))
"False"
print (hasattr(Foo, 'BAR'))
"True"
"""
f = Foo()
print (f.BAR)
"bip"
"""
```

Comment: Это пример с хабра, ошибку вы не нашли,  результат тот же